# facebook checkin: how to find place id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, checkin

I want to do a server-side check-in. I have the coordinates, which is lat-long; I know the name and street address of the business. Is there a way to get the placeId for the parameter Parameter.with("place", 1234)?

```
FacebookType publishCheckinResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/checkins",
  FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", "I'm here!"),
    Parameter.with("coordinates", coordinates), Parameter.with("place", 1234)));
```

Comment: Do you get response on it or any Solution.? I am also looking for same thing. Plz help

Answer (score 3):

If you know the lat-long co-ordinates, why not use Graph API to get the data -
Eg - https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1&access_token=...
This comes from the Graph API doc here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/